# How to retrieve data in slots using Entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table named Material, which consists of nearly 4500000 records.
I want to retrieve all these records using entity framework but it is 
taking more time to select all the records. Sometimes after few minutes 
I am getting `Out of memory exception`.

Can somebody please help me to retrieve the records 100000 at a time,
process them and then retrieve the next records from Database using Entity framework.

Comment: You could make your query Take and Skip records and do it inside some logic with a iteration, maybe a ´For´ or a ´While´,

Comment: What code you are using? One can optimize code if one can see it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean that you want to have a paging mechanism while retrieving data through EF. I would use a [repository](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) to control the whole data access and provide there a more generic mechanism of paging. By "paging", we mean that the results will be returned organized in pages containing a specific number of results.

In the end, you could use queries having a `Skip` and `Take` clause. For example:

```
IQueryable query = ... //form the actual query which is not executed yet
IQueryable pagedQuery = query.Skip(pagesToSkip*recordsPerPage).Take(recordsPerPage); //This is the paged query returning the results of one page
```

Hope I helped!